# Have a server reject API calls from Android app signed with improper key

Tags: android, certificate, code-signing

I've got an open-source Android application in Playstore. The application is signed with my developer key. The application makes some API calls to my server and can feed the server some data.

Now, my concern is that a malicious user can take the open-source code, modify it and start sending bogus data to my server. Thus I would like the app to somehow include its signature in the API calls, and have the server reject data submitted by applications which are not signed with the expected developer key.

Any pointers?

Comment: I think it's not possible. You could modify the the APK which is on play store and add some sort of token with the request.

Comment: Well I found this: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html - not 100% what I want, but looks like a signed app can get a tokenID from the Playstore that proves the app's (package,signature) pair, send this tokenID over in a body part of a HTTP POST request, and then the tokenID can be verified server-side.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I like Varun's suggestion though. The TokenID from Playstore seems like an overkill in this case.
I'll simply include a salted hash in every API call, and the salt will be secret, not stored in the public code repository.

Comment: That would be perfect!